# swift show loader while reading data from firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

i have a list of music at my firebase real time database  and i am retriving them but i have 1000 musics data and i want to show loader when i reading  data and stop loader  when if there is a error(internet connection, or something else) or reading completed.

when i turn off the internet i couldn't get the data and can't stop loader to show error alert like there is no internet connection.

please help me how to handle that problem.

here is my code

didload function called from viewdidload()

```
   private var musicArray = [ItemModal]() {
        didSet {
            view?.updateTableView()
        }
    }

  func didLoad() {
        view?.showLoader()
        getAllMusics { ItemModal in
            self.musicArray = ItemModal
            self.view?.hideLoader()
        }
    }

   func getAllMusics(completion: @escaping ([ItemModal]) -> Void) {
        var musicArray = [ItemModal]()
 
        ref.child("music").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            let enumerator = snapshot.children
            while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
                guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: rest.value as Any, options: []) else { return }
                if let itemModal = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ItemModal.self, from: data) {
                    musicArray.append(itemModal)
                }
            }
           completion(musicArray)
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's called User Presence and the Firebase Realtime Database fully supports it through `onDisconnect`. There's a [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html) about it as well as [hundreds of questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5Duser+presence) here on SO. Also, `.observeSingleEvent(of: .value)` loads all of the data at once and when its all loaded the code within the closure executes. You'll need to change that and read, for example, 10 songs at a time to allow the code to know when the app has disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reachability function by using https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift. To get to notify when the internet is turned off, you can implement reachabilityChanged Notification. In the selector method of reachabilityChanged, you can hide the loader.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachabilityChanged), name: .reachabilityChanged)
}

@objc func changed() {
    if reachability?.isReachable {
        //Continue success implementation
    } else {
        view?.hideLoder
        //Implement Error handling
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer  but this solution is only for internet connection is there any option to handle all errors,like error completion block. @Aishwarya Lakshmi

Comment: You can use  getData method of firebase which is mentioned in the link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write. This gives the error in completion block.

Comment: Yeah - good try but this won't work for the OP's use case as is; they're loading all of the data at once (.observeSingleEvent) and the code following the call won't function (nor will the example in this answer) fire until it fails. See my comment to the Question.